# Can we exclude tsconfig.spec.json from an angular application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-cli

I'm a newbie in Angular. I came across the files `tsconfig.app.json`, `tsconfig.spec.json` when angular app was installed using Angular-CLI and found the following point useful from [this link](https://edvins.io/deep-dive-into-the-angular-cli/).

> Both tsconfig.*.json files are for TypeScript configuration.
>   tsconfig.app.json is used for compiling the code, while
>   tsconfig.spec.json for compiling the tests.

My doubt is, can we completely exclude `tsconfig.spec.json` file if we are not using any test environment? Or is `tsconfig.spec.json` mandatory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't use tests, feel free to remove `tsconfig.spec.json`.

Actually you can generate a new angular app without setting up test environment (karma, protractor and `*.spec.ts` files)

for @angular/cli version 7,8,9 the command is:

```
ng new --minimal=true --skipTests=true your-app-name
```

for @angular/cli version 6:

```
ng new --minimal --skip-tests your-app-name
```

This will remove unnecessary complexity from configuration files which is a nice thing if you just started learning angular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use when create your component or service using `ng g c --skipTests=true`