# What does tsconfig.spec.json do?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898013/difference-between-tsconfig-json-and-tsconfig-app-json-files-in-angular) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798431/use-of-tsconfig-app-json) posts and they have made me understand `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.json`.

I have an angular app which has `tsconfig.app.json`, `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`

What is the role of `tsconfig.spec.json`? What does the `'spec'` in `tsconfig.spec.json` stand for?

Comment: It is for testing.

Comment: I believe 'spec' is short for specification(s). The idea - as I understand it - is that a package's tests should be checking that the specifications (a codified version of the needs/requirements/expecations/deliberables) are met.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890331/how-to-use-different-tsconfig-file-for-tests and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470511/setting-up-tsconfig-with-spec-test-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865419/can-we-exclude-tsconfig-spec-json-from-an-angular-application

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is TypeScript configuration for the application tests.

For example below code you says

```
"types": ["jasmine", "node"]
```

I will use jasmine for testing on nodejs environment.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types types declaration only describes which ./node_modules/@types/ subfolders are included. The main condition  of tsconfig.spec.json file is to specify test files in   "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts" .    Is the name tsconfig.spec.json just convention?   Can someone use different config file name, e.g. tsconfig.test.json for the same purpose?